# Play 2.5 with Sangria

Tags: scala, playframework, sangria

I want to try out Play with Sangria (and Relay and React on top). The Sangria examples I found so far work with Play 2.4.2, but there seem to be some bigger changes in Play 2.5. Would it be better to wait for a new Sangria version, or is it "safe" to update to Play 2.5 right now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be safe to update because sangria itself does not have any dependency on play. The only question is whether [sangria-play-json](https://github.com/sangria-graphql/sangria-play-json) needs to be updated. I'll check it during next days and will update all related example projects and sangria-play-json integration library if necessary.

Comment: Just published sangria-play-json v0.2.1 with play-json v2.5.0 dependency. We also updated the playground projects (which are play apps)

Answer (score 1):

The [sangria-relay-playgound](https://github.com/sangria-graphql/sangria-relay-playground) project has been updated to play 2.5.0. Informe us if you run on any issue.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes

Answer (score 1):

[Boilerplay](https://github.com/sangria-graphql/sangria-relay-playground) has been updated to play 2.6.0 and the latest Sangria, it should serve as a good example for recent Play versions.